# How to create item with column that has strange SharePoint internal encoding?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I created a column with the name "col1" in the list through the web interface Office 365. When I tried to get whole info about this column using msgraph request to

> **GET** /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns/{column-id}

I got such the response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": ...,
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "",
    "displayName": "col1",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": "a9fe9dc8-c5b8-467d-8504-23d95f1cc937",
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "_x0063_ol1",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "number": {
        "decimalPlaces": "automatic",
        "displayAs": "number",
        "maximum": 1.7976931348623157e+308,
        "minimum": -1.7976931348623157e+308
    }
}
```

So the problem is that I cannot create an item with that column (I tried both names **"col1"** and **"_x0063_ol1"**). The request was to

> **POST** /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items

with the body:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Test2",
    "_x0063_ol1": 42
  }
}
```

I got response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Field '_x0063_ol1' is not recognied",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "dbb98ed3-0c2f-48dc-924e-dd888e70c867",
            "date": "2018-05-02T07:41:36"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I properly create the item with this column using msgraph API?